# Adding arrows to my javascript slider

Tags: javascript

I have this image slider:

```
<div class="image-slider">
        <div class="arrows">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
            </div>
```

This is my javascript for making it slide the images automatically:

```
var imageArray = [
    './images/image-slider1.jpg',
    './images/image-slider2.jpg',
    './images/image-slider3.jpg',
];

var index = 0;
imageDuration = 6000;

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('image').src = imageArray[index];
    index++;
    if (index == imageArray.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout('slideShow()', imageDuration);
}

slideShow();
```

How can I make the left arrow show the previous slide and the right one the next?

Comment: Did you try something? That's kinda basic.

Comment: I tried removing  -1 index for the left and + 1 for the right but it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following, I didn't tested it:

```
var imageArray = [
    './images/image-slider1.jpg',
    './images/image-slider2.jpg',
    './images/image-slider3.jpg',
];

var index = 0;
var timerId = null;
var imageDuration = 6000;

function slideShow() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    document.getElementById('image').src = imageArray[index];
    index = (index + 1) % imageArray.length;
    timerId = setTimeout('slideShow()', imageDuration);
}

document
  .querySelector('div.arrows i.fa-arrow-circle-left')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    index = index == 0 ? imageArray.length - 1 : index - 1;
    slideShow();
  });

document
  .querySelector('div.arrows i.fa-arrow-circle-right')
  .addEventListener('click', () => slideShow());

slideShow();
```

Regards,
Vincent